# Grafana input data not in UTC

Tags: sql-server, grafana

I am relatively new to grafana and as a visualization tool, it's been fantastic. The major issue I have is I have some pretty legacy systems that log based on the server's time (which is always in Eastern time) From what I have noticed, grafana is always expecting the data source time to be UTC.

Is there a way to get the timezone of a data source in eastern time for a Microsoft SQL Server data source?  Or potentially a plugin that could do the conversion? Or is my only option code like this in every query
`dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, getdate(), getutcdate()), l.date) as date,`

Comment: Your proposed logic is faulty. You cannot simply add the offset for the **current datetime** to past dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to apply a specific timezone/offset **by DataSource** in Grafana.
In Grafana it can be [managed](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/preferences/change-grafana-timezone/) as a Server/Org/user setting, by default it uses *the timezone in your web browser* which I think works fine in most use cases.

Your workaround works fine and the only other option I'm aware of is to use the [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), which does not solve the fact that you will have to put it more or less everywhere.

The only way I see to centralize the timezone conversions is to create a view  (or maybe a function) that handles the conversion, therefore standardizing the timezone of those legacy systems.
If possible I'd go for the view as it is the most transparent solution I can think of.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I was thinking as well. I will see what is possible from that side with our systems.